# A function whose derivative is negative on $D_f$ but $f$ is not strictly decreasing on $D_f$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm studying the derivate and monotonicity of functions, and was wondering if such a function exists.

Comment: Please use the body of the Question to give a self-contained presentation of the problem.  In particular a proper statement of the problem would define what $D_f$ means.

Answer (score 2):

If $D_f$ does not need to be connected, the examples are legion: Consider, for example, the domain $D_f = (0,1) \cup(1,2)$ and the map 
\begin{align*} 
  f \colon D_f &\to \mathbf R \\
           x &\mapsto \begin{cases} -x & x < 1\\ 2-x & x > 1 \end{cases}
\end{align*}Then $f \in C^1(D_f)$ mit $f'(x) = -1$, $x \in D_f$, but 
$f(\frac 12) = -\frac 12 \not> \frac 12 = f(\frac 32)$.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better to use "interval" instead of "connected", as the two are the same in $\Bbb R$ and the latter might confuse some.